# How can I install a water softener in my basement with no floor drain?

Tags: water-softener

Drain lines for house are in the joists in the ceiling in basement.

I could route the softener drain into the sump pump temporarily, but thats not really optimal.

I understand the need an air gap for the softener waste drain but to do that all I can see is bringing the softener drain line up into the kitchen under the sink and dumping it down that drain with an air gap.

There is a horizonal pipe in the basement near the softener.  Can I dump into the horizontal pipe or are there other alternatives?

[image: drain pic 1a]

[image: drain pic 1b]

Comment: You'd have to tell us what that "horizontal pipe" is for before we can answer that. Chance are you can't open it up down low. Normally you'd do something like you describe. A laundry room might be better.

Comment: Horizontal pipe is drain pipe, about 6 feet above where the softener is going to go.  it has a cleanout plug in it but no clearance above for vertical air gap.  yeah laundry room is sub-optimal but could work too

Comment: That doesn't tell us much. Please provide a sketch or photographs.

Comment: Drain pipes in the ceiling ? So why not use the sump pump?  If you have to pump you have to pump, set up a new sump that will hold 1 recharge cycle of water and pump it if the sump won’t work. Photos of the mystery pipes may help us understand what you have.

Comment: @EdBeal, I read that using normal sump wasnt the greatest for it due to salt / chemical content of softener waste water

Comment: Yes the softener has salt but it goes down a drain one way or the other, really hard on a septic where is the discharge for your sump?  Can’t be as bad as the septic system.

Comment: discharge for basement sump is outside, not in septic.

Comment: A friend suggested a ball check valve at that cleanout in the pics.

Comment: My softener has been discharging into my sump pit for 25+ years. I've had one sump pump failure in that time. If the salinity is killing my sump pump, it's still at an acceptable rate for me.